# Formula that will physically remove data from one table and place it into another

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Is there a formula I could use to essentially cut and remove a row of data if a condition exists and have it move to a different table? I know how to get the data to simply transfer, but I'm trying to avoid duplicates in the data.

Comment: No, a formula will not do that.  You will need vba to do that.

Answer (score -1):

Formulas in Excel can only find data elsewhere and use it, or create information themselves and use it. They cannot format said data in any way.

(Seeming exceptions like `TEXT()` which are really transforming the data into another form (a string in this case) and that form is then acted upon by Excel in some way chosen outside the formula's purview. So it could change a numeric value like "1" to a string, say, "1.000" but that string is subject to whatever formatting, chosen or default, Excel is applying to strings in that cell.)

Various display effects can be created separately via formal formatting or via Conditional Formatting's functionality, but even though they act upon formulas, and in the case of CF, may USE formulas in their conditions, it is never any of the formulas themselves performing these things, but rather the formatting or CF-ing functionalities themselves.

The only way formulas in Excel CAN do as you ask is if the data for your various output tables is in some other place than those tables AND if those tables use formulas to retrieve the data that belongs in them from those tables.

You don't want duplication of data, and that is not such. The data exists in ONE place, and is displayed as required in other places. No change in those other places affects the data itself. Only changes that happen to the data directly have any effect upon it. An analogy might be a TV show or better, a show in the internet. The show exists in one place and is displayed as required in potentially millions. Nothing done in the places displayed affects the show. Only a change in the single place it exists affects it. Choices made at the display ends might affect what is displayed at those places, but not the underlying data.

So... if you are using Excel as a data store, you will have the desired lack of duplication. However, most any such use actually wants to be able to change the underlying data, so the next problem arises.

And VBA in one form or another is how you solve that problem and all the problems going down that path leads to.

What is described above would require a data store that has the data PLUS characteristics (which can be values of the data, not just additional information) that allow your output tables to choose which data to display. You could make a change to these characteristics that makes one table stop including that data and makes a second table begin including it. The EFFECT of cutting it from one place and pasting in another is achieved, but there is never any actual cutting and pasting as such is not actually required.

Without VBA, that'd be hard to implement for display purposes and much nastier to do for anything interactive, if possible at all. So for almost any use you have in mind, as `Scott Craner` says:  VBA.